# command File multiple import of csv files

Tags: csv, hana

i would like to import csv files into a hana database. It's working fine with a control file that look like this:

```
IMPORT DATA  
INTO TABLE "schema"."table"
FROM '/table'
RECORD DELIMITED BY '\n'
FIELD DELIMITED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '“'
ERROR LOG '/errorlog'
```

is there a chance to import different csv files in different tables? 
Like:

```
IMPORT DATA  
INTO TABLE "schema"."table"
FROM '/table'
RECORD DELIMITED BY '\n'
FIELD DELIMITED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '“'
ERROR LOG '/errorlog'

IMPORT DATA  
INTO TABLE "schema"."table2"
FROM '/table2'
RECORD DELIMITED BY '\n'
FIELD DELIMITED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '“'
ERROR LOG '/errorlog'
```

i hope you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright,
why don't you switch on the multi command mode in HDBSQL then and separate the IMPORT DATA statements with the statement separator (usually semicolon ;)?

Just as you would do with any other set of SQL commands.